# How can I convert a numpy array (wav data) to int16 with Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, wav, soundfile

I have some data that I assume is `wav` data. If I use:

```
soundfile.write(filepath, my_data, samplerate)
```

, then it correctly writes a `wav` file. But I want to somehow convert that wav data to `int16` as currently it's some sort of `float`:

```
[0.0018415  0.00730521 0.01155283 ... 0.10048427 0.09344029 0.08903081]
```

with

```
max 0.3002103
min -0.33075073
```

It came from a process in https://github.com/santi-pdp/segan_pytorch

Is there some way for me to convert to `int16` this without having to save and then read a file?

Comment: _as currently it's some sort of float_ Can you check what it actually is? You've given practically no information here, can you please be more specific? Where is the file coming from? What libraries are you using?

Comment: Added more detail outlining the problem

Comment: It's a numpy array? What's the `.dtype`? Do you want to just change the type to int16, or do you want to scale the data as well?

Comment: I want to scale the data to the same that would have happened if I read with soundfile.read(dtype=int16)

Comment: Is the data currently in the range [0, 1[ ? You write that you _assume_ the data is in the wav format, can you be more specific?

Comment: @AMC I added the `min` and `max` of the array

Comment: I assume it's `wav` because when I `soundfile.write` it as a wav, it works

Comment: @Shamoon does `soundfile.read(dtype=int16)` do linear scaling or logarithmic?

Comment: @Shamoon That doesn’t sound very scientific lmao. Is that all you know about the array?

Comment: That's about all I do know unfortunately.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I'm not sure and the docs don't state

Comment: @Shamoon. Actually they do. The library will round but not scale

Comment: So then what do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer was simple enough:

```
my_data = (my_data * 32767).astype(np.int16)
```